# How to highlight joined features?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a task in QGIS (2.6), where I need to join two tables through an action (I think).

I have some projects (points) that I need to connect to a list of partners (also points). I have data in both PostGres and as simple files.
What I want is to be able to click on a project and then I will be able to get the partners highlighted/shown.

Is that at all possible in QGIS or would it be easier to do it in the database?